# How to Monitor servers with SNMP?

Tags: snmp, snmpwalk

I  am linux new user, and want to monitor my linux server with SNMP protocol to get some cpu, memory info, how do I use the snmp to monitor linux system? how to monitor linux servers with snmp?

Comment: are you asking for a specific software application to do this or rather a script?

Answer (score 1):

SNMP(Simple Network Management protocol) is a standard TCP/IP protocol for network management. Network administrators use SNMP to monitor and map network availability, performance, and error rates. it allows you to monitor the health of many system devices.this document will describe how to setup SNMP service.

**Install SNMP on Debian or Ubuntu system**

The SNMP service daemon is snmpd , to install it type the following command:

> [root@devops~]# apt-get install snmpd

snmpd is now installed but we still need to edit snmpd configure file(/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf) like the following:

// Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 and IPv6)

> agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161

//use either your server's domain name or its IP address rocommunity

> yourcommunity 172.16.1.0/254
>
> the options setting is adding the following both "sysLocation" and"sysContact" in
>
> sysLocation LOCATION_NAME   sysContact CONTACT_NAME

After you are done with your modifications and restart snmpd service 1

> [root@devops~]# /etc/init.d/snmpd retsart

**Checking SNMP configuration**

we are able to use the snmpwalk tools to test the SNMP configuration. if you get pages of output, the SNMP has been set up successfully. 1

> [root@devops~]#snmpwalk -Oav -v2c -c youcommunity 172.17.16.2

OR

[root@devops~]#sudo service snmpd restart

via: http://itsprite.com/linuxhow-to-monitor-your-linux-servers-via-snmp-protocol/